# TYPO3 - RouteEnhancer adds parameter from other plugin

Tags: typo3

My RouteEnhancers seems to overlap.
I have multiple plugins with Pagination, all with own Controllers in other Extensions (here MyextAds is the example)

shortened version:

```
routeEnhancers:
  Ads:
    type: Extbase
    extension: MyextAds
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/', _controller: 'Ad::list' }
      - { routePath: '/seite-{adPaginationPage}', _controller: 'Ad::list', _arguments: { 'adPaginationPage': '@widget_0/currentPage'}}
  News:
    type: Extbase
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/', _controller: 'News::list' }
      - { routePath: '/seite-{newsPaginationPage}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'newsPaginationPage': '@widget_0/currentPage'} }
```

When I switch to `/page-2` in `Ads->list`, i see the content of Page 1 and the pagination link to page 2 has a new parameter:

```
...../seite-2?tx_news_pi1%5B%40widget_0%5D%5BcurrentPage%5D=2&tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=list&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&cHash=...
```

the MyextAds doesn't know anything about news - why is this parameter added?
If i add a new url part like this (/somethig/...), its working:

```
- { routePath: '/something/seite-{adPaginationPage}', _controller: 'Ad::list', _arguments: { 'adPaginationPage': '@widget_0/currentPage'}}
```

But this is breaking my URL-Schema :/

Am I doing something wrong or is it definitly needed to add an additional url-part?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you have to add an extra segment into one of the paginations, otherwise it is indistinguishable to the routing to which the page number should be assigned.